# Robot moves forward only

Tags: ros, navigation, navfn, move-base, base-local-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

Robot goes into narrow place but it can't go back to first position. It is trying to escape with moving  a bit backward (then forward) infinitely at corridor's end. How can I make it escape all the way backwards?  My Local Planner : `base_local_planner/TrajectoryPlannerROS`
Gmapping's Hokuyo Laser is in the front of robot. And There is a small rplidar on the robot's rear for avoiding obstacles:

```
obstacle_layer:
     observation_sources: rplidar_back_scan scan
     rplidar_back_scan: {data_type: LaserScan, sensor_frame: /base_lidar_back_link, clearing: true, marking: true, topic: /rplidar_back_scan}
     scan: {data_type: LaserScan, sensor_frame: /base_laser_link, clearing: true, marking: true, topic: /scan}
```

Here is Rviz screenshot:

[image description http://s21.postimg.org/c3pakik6v/ROSSAN.png](http://s21.postimg.org/c3pakik6v/ROSSAN.png)

Thank you.

EDIT1: Am I need to merge lasers? (And how to merge?) `move_base` updating costmap with all laser's scans but Gmapping uses only front laser.

EDIT2: I've set `escape_vel` to `0.0`. Now robot just stopping at the corridor's end.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/225835/robot-moves-forward-only/) by [Orhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25268/orhan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 856 on 2016-02-04

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [F.Brosseau](https://answers.ros.org/users/22477/f.brosseau/) on 2016-02-05**:
Maybe you can try to modify the *escape_reset_theta* parameter.
http://docs.ros.org/hydro/api/base_local_planner/html/classbase__local__planner_1_1TrajectoryPlanner.html

**Comment by [Orhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25268/orhan/) on 2016-02-05**:
Thank you. But `escape_reset_theta` and `escape_reset_dist` parameters aren't useful. Now it is `0.01`. If I set this to `1.0`, robot tries escape one meter for every obstacle.

**Comment by [F.Brosseau](https://answers.ros.org/users/22477/f.brosseau/) on 2016-02-05**:
And with the oscillation_reset_dist  parameter?

**Comment by [Orhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25268/orhan/) on 2016-02-05**:
I've tried before, It doesn't make sense too. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have found solution. From David Lu's this answer: [how to remove forward bias in move_base](http://answers.ros.org/question/207377/how-to-remove-forward-bias-in-move_base/?answer=207390#post-id-207390)

I've changed local planner to `dwa_local_planner/DWAPlannerROS` and setted `min_vel_x` to negative value. Now robot goes backward succesfully.

---

Originally posted by [Orhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25268/orhan/) with karma: 856 on 2016-02-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1